# How to check if the device is a "1st generation Kindle Fire " or other version?

Tags: android, android-layout, kindle, kindle-fire

In my application I need to check if the device is a "1st generation Kindle Fire" or other version. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to check with the Build Model

```
android.os.Build.MODEL

KFJWA       - Kindle Fire HD 8.9" WAN               
KFJWI       - Kindle Fire HD 8.9" Wi-Fi
KFTT        - Kindle Fire HD 7"
KFOT        - Kindle Fire (2nd Gen)
Kindle Fire -Kindle Fire (1st Gen)
```

[Link here:](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/specifications.html)

In general, apps optimized for a tablet experience will work on Kindle Fire tablets. To improve compatibility with the Kindle tablets, we recommend you use APIs that are backwards compatible with the Android 4.0.3 platform (Ice Cream Sandwich API 15) for the Kindle Fire (2nd Generation), Kindle Fire HD 7", and Kindle Fire HD 8.9"; and with the Android 2.3.3 platform (Gingerbread API 10) for Kindle Fire (1st Generation).

Comment: Thanks for this. We have to special case Camera usage on the original Kindle Fire, as for some inexplicable reason it returns "1" for `Camera.getNumberOfCameras()` and returns a `Camera` object for `Camera.open()`, even though **it has no camera hardware**.

Answer (score 0):

Useful Build constants for all Kindle Fire devices to date:

### `android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE`:

- 1st Gen: `2.3.3`
- 2nd Gen: `4.0.3`
- 3rd Gen: `4.2.2`

### `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`

- 1st Gen: `10`
- 2nd Gen: `15`
- 3rd Gen: `17`

### `android.os.Build.MODEL`

#### Kindle Fire HDX 8.9" (3rd Gen):

- WAN: `KFAPWA`
- Wi-fi: `KFAPWI`

#### Kindle Fire HDX 7" (3rd Gen):

- WAN: `KFTHWA`
- Wi-fi: `KFTHWI`

#### Kindle Fire HD 7" (3rd Gen):

- `KFSOWI`

#### Kindle Fire HD 8.9" (2nd Gen):

- WAN: `KFJWA`
- Wi-fi: `KFJWI`

#### Kindle Fire HD 7" (2nd Gen):

- `KFTT`

#### Kindle Fire (2nd Gen):

- `KFOT`

#### Kindle Fire (1st Gen):

- `Kindle Fire`